# Crear Diccionario desde un DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Estoy realizando la extraccion de datos de una tabla en SQL Server y cargando los datos en un DataFrame, con la información que tengo en 02 columnas ([ItemGroup],[ItemModule]) necesito crear un diccionario, por ejemplo en el DF tengo los siguientes valores:

```
   ItemGroup  ItemModule
0         99        9901
1         55        5505
2         55        5503
3         55        5500
4         99        9902
5         55        5501
6          3         300
7         55        5504
8         99        9903
9         55        5502
```

**Lo que necesito es crear un diccionario que quede así: `{99: [9901, 9902, 9903], 55: [5500,5501,5502,5503,5504,5505], 3: [300]}`**

He usado .to_dict() con el DF pero lo que me crea es el diccionario considerando como clave los encabezados y me incluye el index: `{'ItemGroup': {0: 99, 1: 55, 2: 55, 3: 55, 4: 99, 5: 55, 6: 55, 7: 99, 8: 55}, 'ItemModule': {0: 9901, 1: 5505, 2: 5503, 3: 5500, 4: 9902, 5: 5501, 6: 5504, 7: 9903, 8: 5502}}`

Answer (score 2):

Casi usas el método correcto, aunque el que te interesa es `pandas.Series.to_dict()`, pero tienes que procesar algo el DataFrame primero. Básicamente agrupar por la columna `ItemGroup` y aplicar `list` sobre `ItemModule` por cada grupo:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "ItemGroup": (99, 55, 55, 55, 99, 55, 3, 55, 99, 55),
    "ItemModule": (9901, 5505, 5503, 5500, 9902, 5501, 300, 5504, 9903, 5502)}
    )
```

> ```
> >>> df
>
>    ItemGroup  ItemModule
> 0         99        9901
> 1         55        5505
> 2         55        5503
> 3         55        5500
> 4         99        9902
> 5         55        5501
> 6          3         300
> 7         55        5504
> 8         99        9903
> 9         55        5502
> ```

```
dicc = df.groupby("ItemGroup")["ItemModule"].apply(list).to_dict()
```

> ```
> >>> dicc
> {3: [300], 55: [5505, 5503, 5500, 5501, 5504, 5502], 99: [9901, 9902, 9903]}
> ```

En tu salida esperada parece que buscas que las listas queden ordenadas de forma ascendente, de ser así, puedes ordenar la columna previamente a agrupar:

```
dicc = (df.sort_values(["ItemModule"], ascending=True)
          .groupby("ItemGroup")["ItemModule"]
          .apply(list)
          .to_dict()
          )
```

> ```
> >>> dicc
> {3: [300], 55: [5500, 5501, 5502, 5503, 5504, 5505], 99: [9901, 9902, 9903]}
> ```

Comment: Es como la tercera pregunta idéntica que veo esta semana.